# Efficient way to insert multiple file links (residing in the same directory) into a org file with helm

Tags: org-mode, helm, org-link

Suppose I edit an org-file, say `/foo/bar/file.org` and I want to insert links to multiple files living in another path, say `/another/path/to/files/`.

A stupid way to do this would be to call `helm-find-files`, navigate from `/foo/bar/` to `/another/path/to/file` and insert the link to the first file via `C-c @` (and enter the link name/description). Then I repeat the complete procedure for all other files.

Slightly more efficient would it be to use `helm-resume` with universal argument (e.g. `C-u C-c h b`) and then resume `find files`. Then there is no need to navigate from one path to the other each time.

I also tried to mark multiple files (via `Alt-SPACE`) and then press `C-c @`, but that doesn't work.

So is there a significantly more efficient way to do the same job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since current `helm-find-files` command does not support to insert multiple candidates as org links, a rough improvement can be made as follows:

```lisp
(defun helm-files-insert-as-org-link (candidate)
  (let* ((marked-files (helm-marked-candidates :with-wildcard t)))
    (dolist (file marked-files)
      (let ((target (expand-file-name (helm-substitute-in-filename file))))
        (insert (format "[[file:%s] " file))))))
```

Use Ctrl-SPACE to mark multiple candidates, and insert them.

Comment: See my post: I already tried this, but `C-c @` doesn't work with this.

Comment: Okay, you are right. It does not work. I will try to figure out a solution. One question: Would you like to insert all files as links in the folder or just part of them? That will make the solution different.

Comment: Just a part of them which I may have to select *manually* (sometimes there might be a pattern in the filenames I want, so selecting it via a regexp would be elegant, but this would be another question).

Comment: @student  see the edits